# How to add shortcode to custom text on first page block

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I would like to add shortcode to my homepage test.healthclubone.nl. In the dashboard is the 'custom text first page' available. The shortcode needs to be between the header and the widget.

However, the shortcode is seen as text and not as HTML. Is there a possibility to change this? I played around with do_shortcode but this is not working. Thanks for your help.

Wobin

Answer (score 0):

the definitely thing that if you are calling slider in the home page template, you should use do_shortcode right after slider.

As I could see there is an empty carousel right before widgets, which means that shortcode does not function well, so it's better to check shortocde functionality/options.

Comment: Hi, 
I have the following code in my index.php. Is there a way to edit this so that shortcodes work? <div id="custom_text" style="padding-left:10px;">
<?php echo ot_get_option('custom_text_first_page');?>
</div>

Comment: What is "custom_text_first_page" ?
Have you tested shortcode directly in the page content, does it work?

Comment: Hi, yes then it does work. The problem is that I can only add content for the homepage in the custom text box. However, that is seen as text and not html. Are they any possibilities for this?

Comment: still don't get it :) skype @ oliver.white44 I'll help u with that